# Kendo Ui in asp.net core mvc unable to get the DataValueField value

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I am using the kendo multi column dropdown but I appear to be unable to get the value from the DatValueField I am using the value to then get the id of the person selected to be able to store that in another table.

If anyone can show me how to replicae the same in bootstrap please do telerik is not my only answer here would rather avoid it tbh

```
<form asp-action="LinkToCase" method="post" asp-controller="MISObjects">

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card card-success">

        <div class="card-header" style="background-color:#1e3f5a;color:white">
            <h3 class="card-title">Search and Tag</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <select id="searchOptions" name="searchOptions" style="background-color: #1e3f5a; color: white; width: 140px; height: 45px">
                        <option selected value="1">Poi</option>
                        <option selected value="1">Vessel</option>
                    </select>


                    @(Html.Kendo().MultiColumnComboBox()
                        .Name("tagItem")
                        .DataTextField("name")
                        .DataValueField("SearchId")
                        .Filter("contains")
                        .FilterFields(new string[] { "name", "ContactTitle", "CompanyName", "Country" })
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Add().Field("name").Title("Contact Name").Width("200px");
                            columns.Add().Field("dob").Title("Date Of Brith").Width("200px");

                        })
                        .FooterTemplate("Total #: instance.dataSource.total() # items found")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:80%;" })
                        .Height(400)
                        .DataSource(source => source
                            .Custom()
                            .Transport(transport => transport
                                .Read(read =>
                                {
                                    read.Action("SearchQuery", "MISObjects")
                                        .Data("onAdditionalData");
                                }))
                        )
                        )
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary" value="Link To Case" style=" background-color:#1e3f5a;color:white">Link To Case</button>

                 </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

The kendo combox calls this function.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult LinkToCase(int SearchId,string updateInfo, int tagItem, string sesearchOptionsr, IFormCollection formItems) {
    
      Int32.TryParse(TempData.Peek("CaseId").ToString(), out int resultCaseId);
      var test = formItems;
        POI newPoi = new POI();
        newPoi =  _context.Pois.SingleOrDefault(w => w.Id == SearchId);

        newPoi.MISObjectId = resultCaseId;

        _context.Pois.Add(newPoi);

        _toast.AddSuccessToastMessage(
            $"You have linked {newPoi.FirstName} {newPoi.LastName} to case {resultCaseId:d8}");

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = resultCaseId });

    }
    private IEnumerable<SearchViewModel> GetSearchRecords() {
        return _context.Pois.Where(w => w.isActive == true && w.isDeleted == false).Select(person =>
             new SearchViewModel {
                 SearchId = person.Id,
                 Name = person.FirstName + "  " + person.LastName,
                 DOB = person.DOB
             }).ToList();

  }
```

But even when I inspect SearchId it is blank even if i set it to type int I put in a support ticket as I am on trail but saw their was a kendo tag here so thought might try here as well

**Edit 2**

As you can see below the value is not anywhere to be found in the form collection items.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code correctly, it appears to me that the SearchId value you want should already be in the tagItem int parameter in your controller method, since that is the name of the MultiColumnComboBox in the form. That MultiColumnComboBox is bound to a list that has the SearchId as the value field, which is different and will not get posted back on submit.

Comment: You would think so but its not as what comes back is the persons name not the id

Comment: Could you include your SearchQuery code from the controller and also I found this thread, I know it's not the same control you're using, but the behavior seems to match: https://www.telerik.com/forums/combobox-saves-text-instead-of-value